# Change Fragment to RoboGuice Fragment?

Tags: java, android, roboguice

I'm trying to use RoboGuice in my App. My first try is to change a simple Fragment to RoboFragment.
But after the app cannot compile anymore. What could be the problem here?

```
class MyFragment extends RoboFragment {

        @InjectView(R.id.progress_bar) private static ProgressBar progressBar;
    }
```

Results in:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(1237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{path.to.MyApp}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: 
Error inflating class fragment
.
```

/edit:

I think my problem is that within the progress bar fragment I'm doing this:

```
public static void setProgressBar(Activity parent, int visible) {
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) parent.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
}
```

This might probably not work with RoboGuice injection?

```
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:251)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:109)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  ... 11 more
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MyActivity@412f8b38 does not appear to be a RoboGuice context (instanceof RoboContext)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.getScopedObjectMap(ContextScope.java:147)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.enter(ContextScope.java:79)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:241)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at roboguice.fragment.RoboFragment.onCreate(RoboFragment.java:13)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:834)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1156)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:270)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post the full logcat output including all exceptions, we can try to find out which one is the one you should fix. The xml inflate line 34 has your .fragment in it, there should be exceptions shown by the fragment in the logcat output that tell you which line in the fragment contains the error.

Your stack trace says

> 06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MyActivity@412f8b38 does not
>   appear to be a RoboGuice context (instanceof RoboContext)

Is your Activity a RoboFragmentActivity?

Comment: made an edit above. Probably that I'm using parent for progress bar is a problem with injection?

Comment: You inject a progressBar into the Fragment, so you have a ProgressBar. Then you want to change it to the ProgressBar of the Activity, which is not in view. It's a lot easier to just use the ProgressBar that you injected into the Fragment. Also your stack trace says "06-10 12:06:23.063: E/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MyActivity@412f8b38 does not appear to be a RoboGuice context (instanceof RoboContext)" Is your Activity a RoboFragmentActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the "progressBar" field static?

Comment: to access the progressbar from within any activity, because several should be able to start and cancel the same progress bar.

Comment: This is a bad practice, you should reconsider your design

Comment: What's exactly bad practice? Or how could I do better?

Comment: Sharing class instances via static member is not good. Why do you want to share the same progress bar? Why not to let every activity have its own progress bar?

Comment: Because different activities should tigger the SAME progress bar. nothing special, but useful in my case. What is other opportunity than using static members for this??